# Why browser.text.include? produces error in Watir Ruby script

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

**Issue:**  I have researched online on how to verify if text exists on my page, but I keep getting error messages.  I have attempted using "expect" and one without "expect".  For something that seems basic, I am not sure why this is not asserting correctly.

**Ruby File:**

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "rspec"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec/expectations"
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :internet_explorer

begin
 if expect(@browser.text.include?("Welcome")).to be_true
 #@browser.text.include?("Welcome").should == true

    puts "Test passed!"
  else
    puts "Test failed!"
  end
end
```

**Error:**

> test2.rb:61:in `<main>': undefined method`expect' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

You should have your expectations defined inside a test case

```
describe "IE" do
  it "should have test 'Welcome'" do
     expect(@browser.text.include("Welcome")).to be_true
  end
end
```

Or if you just want your script to print pass or fail, just do

```
begin
 if @browser.text.include?("Welcome")
    puts "Test passed!"
  else
    puts "Test failed!"
  end
end
```

Comment: I used the begin/end statement, but it is showing false.  It is under div class, span id, text (welcome).  Do I need to specify div, class, spanid?  I tried that but it does not see the "Welcome" text.  I used the rercorder tool and it sees "Welcome".

Comment: When I run the script, it opens a new IE explorer window.  Do I need to somehow change focus to this window so it sees it to then see the "Welcome" text?

Comment: This seemed to work to recognize the new window:   @browser.window(:title => "1st Global Pathway").use do
  begin
 if @browser.text.include?("Welcome")
    puts "Test passed!"
  else
    puts "Test failed!"
  end
end
end